# Restart app after 5s when open app from recent application

Tags: android, restart

I click button home or recent application to close app and then I open app from recent application. Now I want if time I close app larger 5s my app will restart. How to do it? thank everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by SharedPreferences and implementing own logic, like when you will press home button store the current time in `onPause()` method and when the user opens the app again then check with the condition with the current time in `onResume()` and the stored value, if its more than 5s then restart it.

One thing remember, when restarting the activity store some negative number in SharedPreference so that, it won't restart again. And to restart the activity write below logic.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: your ideal is when click home button save time current on method onPause() and when open app from recent get time in method on resume(), then check it and restart app with Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i); if its more 5s

Comment: @TrầnHoà exactly, that thing.

Comment: I can restart it but i always show splashactivity.I don't know